# Qlik Sense formatting number field as text or URL

Tags: sql, format, qliksense

I'm loading data to Qlik Sense 3.1 from SQL Server. There are some fields defined as decimal in SQL Sever but when I load them from SQL, they appear as text or URL, so I can't show totals for those fields in the chart. I've tried using num() and num#() functions and there's no change.

This is my data load script

```
ProductosaLiquidar:
    UNQUALIFY *;
    LOAD ID as ID_LIQ,
        Trimestre,
        FechaInicio,
        FechaFin,
        Cod as  [Articulo ID],
        num#(Stock) AS [Stock Liquidacion], 
        Minimo as MinimoLiq,
        Num#(Trim(ObjetivoLiquidar)) as ObjetivoLiquidar,
        num#(puntos,'#,#') as PuntosLiq;
    SQL SELECT ID,
        Trimestre,
        FechaInicio,
        FechaFin,
        Cod,
        Stock,
        Minimo ,
        ObjetivoLiquidar,
        puntos
    FROM [dbo].ObjetivoLiq;
```

Fields as text

[image: Fields as text]

Representation options

[image: Representation options]

Answer (score 1):

From [QS help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Scripting/InterpretationFunctions/num_hash.htm):

> Num#() converts a text string to a numerical value, in the number
>   format set in the data load script or the operating system. Custom
>   decimal and thousand separator symbols are optional parameters.

So if the format of the number returned is different from the operating system setup, you will need to provide custome format for `num#()`. For example:

```
num( num#('123,433.123', '#' ,'.',',') )
```

will convert the string `123,433.123` into a number and the following expression:

```
num( num#('123,433.123', '#' ,'.',',') ) + 100000
```

will return `223433.123`

btw the same is applied and for `date#` function

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it, as you can see in the field [puntos] and with other fields before that, but still no change. At the end, I deleted all charts where those fields were used and made them again. Now it works perfectly without using num#() or any other function
Thank you!